# Regex for Weight

Tags: php, regex

I use this to extract weight information and it works well most of the times:

```
/(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(lbs?|g|kgs?|pounds?|oz|ounces?)\b/i
```

.. except when it comes across `2G`, `3G` etc.. which isn't `gram` obviously.

How do I add a condition so that for `gram` it requires atleast 2 digits?

Comment: Protip: Don't let your users enter data like this. Use a textbox for numeric entry, and a dropdown for unit of weight.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks, but its not user input. I'm extracting data from thousands of documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to split that into a different branch:

```
/((\d*\.?\d+)\s*(lbs|kgs)|(\d\.?\d\d+)\s*(grams))\b/i
```

Comment: `/((\d*\.?\d+)\s*(lbs?|kgs?|pounds?|oz|ounces?)|(\d\.?\d\d+)\s*(g|grams))\b/i` ?